# vs-code: How to inspect string variables that hold json values in debugger?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

Is there a way in vs code to visualize json values stored in variables while debugging? Maybe a recommended extension that could help me with this.

In Visual Studio we have this:

[image: In Visual Studio we have this]

But this in vs code is missing:

[image]

Comment: Kind of similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59756331/how-to-show-the-entire-value-in-vscode-debug-mode - in short, VS Code doesn't easily allow you to view a variable in entirety if its a long string/other object.